# what is the best way to batch replace multiple strings in a text file

Tags: c#, winforms, replace, io

i have this file that have many strings and many replacements, and i want to replace the strings with their replacement, and then save the text file, this is what i tried, it did a bad job though:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fullPath + "\\DICT_J.txt", Encoding.Unicode);
            string cdID;
            string str;
            while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                string[] temp = sr.ReadLine().Split('＾');
                if (temp.Length == 3)
                {
                    cdID = temp[1];
                    str = temp[2];
                    File.WriteAllText(path, Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(path), str, cdID), Encoding.Unicode);
                }
            }
            sr.Close();
            sr.Dispose();
```

[here](http://paste2.org/Vwmfmj7z)(sorry i couldn't post it here because SOF doesn't allow Line returns) is a sample of the file that contains the replacements, and here is the template:
Line ID＾Replacement＾String to be replaced

Comment: Try `System.IO.File.ReadAllText()` method.

Comment: i am sorry, some browser issues with the title, sorry for the misleading title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will help, but these are my guesses.
These methods have other overloads for Encoding that I'm not using here but might be useful in your case.

#### 1. Replace string on original file with the LineID from the replacement's file

```
public void Replace(string originalFile, string replacementsFile)
{
    var originalContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(originalFile);
    var replacements = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(replacementsFile);

    foreach(var replacement in replacements)
    {
        var _split = replacement.Split(new char[] { '^' });

        var lineNumber = Int32.Parse(_split[0]);

        // checks if the original content file has that line number and replaces
        if (originalContent.Length < lineNumber)
            originalContent[lineNumber] = originalContent[lineNumber].Replace(_split[1], _split[2]);
    }

    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(originalFile, originalContent);
}
```

#### 2. Replace every match of a replacement's template on another file

```
public void Replace(string originalFile, string replacementsFile)
{
    var originalContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(originalFile);
    var replacements = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(replacementsFile);

    foreach(var replacement in replacements)
    {
        var _split = replacement.Split(new char[] { '^' });

        originalContent = originalContent.Replace(_split[1], _split[2]);
    }

    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(originalFile, originalContent);
}
```

Comment: thank you, the second method worked flawlessly. +1 to you sir.